# ContextModelSnapshot and Manual Migrations in EF7

Tags: entity-framework-core

With Entity Framework 7 I created the first migration and got two files:

```
20151206224643_InitialDatabaseSetup.cs
ContextModelSnapshot.cs
```

1. What is ContextModelSnapshot for?
2. What if I need to change a migration code?
   For example, using SQL code to create a procedure or add filestream?
3. Can, or should I, add empty migrations and setup the code manually?

Comment: Some useful "context" in https://www.bricelam.net/2014/12/16/ef7-migrations-designtime.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams

Answer (score 4):

> What is ContextModelSnapshot for?

Unlike EF 6, in EF Core there is no more snapshots per migrations stored in database. Instead, there is **one snapshot per context**.

Find out more at http://mehrandvd.me/2016/02/18/entity-framework-core-migrations

Not sure about your 2nd and 3rd questions.

Comment: Dead link - archive copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20230607123111/https://mehrandvd.me/2016/02/18/entity-framework-core-migrations/